# Prime # program identifying false primes

Tags: loops, testing, input, numbers, static-methods

The program just need to take a user input and say whether it's prime or not, then it should ask them if they want to do it again until they don't want to.
Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeOrNot

{


public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int n = 0;
    String reply;
    char doAgain = 'Y';
    boolean valid = false, isPrime = true;

    Welcome();


    do
    {
    System.out.print("Enter a whole number: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    if(PrimeTest(n))
        System.out.println(n + " is a prime number!");
    if(!PrimeTest(n))
        System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number!");

        //Asks the user to try again until they enter a valid
        //response of Y or N
        while(!valid)
        {
        System.out.print("Try another number? (Y/N): ");
        reply = scan.next().toUpperCase();
        doAgain = reply.charAt(0);
        System.out.println();

        if(doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'N')
            valid = true;
        else
            System.out.println("Please type 'Y' or 'N'.");
        }
    }while(doAgain != 'N');


    Goodbye();
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------*/
/********************STATIC METHODS BELOW********************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------*/

/****************************************/
//Welcome method...a welcoming 'graphic'//
/****************************************/
    public static void Welcome()
    {
        System.out.println("=============");
        System.out.println("Prime or Not");
        System.out.println("=============");
        System.out.println();
    }

/****************************************************/
//PrimeTest determines if the number is prime or not//
/****************************************************/
    public static boolean PrimeTest(int n)
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;

    if(n > 0)
    {
        for(int x = 2; x <= Math.sqrt(n); x++)
        {
            if(n % 2 == 0)
                isPrime = false;
            else if(n % x == 0)
                isPrime = false;
            else
                isPrime = true;
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");

    return isPrime;
}

/****************************************/
//Goodbye method...a departing 'graphic'//
/****************************************/
    public static void Goodbye()
        {
            System.out.println("===============");
            System.out.println("Try again soon!");
            System.out.println("===============");
            System.out.println();
        } 

}
```

Here's what's happening. I'll put in a number, and it'll answer most things wrong. Then when I press Y to do another, it just keeps having me enter numbers and telling me if it's prime or not, and will never ask me if I actually want to keep going. I have absolutely no idea how to fix either issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prime test won't work because you keep testing even after you have recognized that it is not a prime. As soon as you find even one divisor then you should set `isPrime` to false and break out of the loop. Don't set it to true on the next test! Also you don't need a separate test for n % 2 since you will test that when x = 2.

```
for(int x = 2; x <= Math.sqrt(n); x++)
{
    if(n % x == 0)
    {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

When you call the function, call it only once and save the result in a boolean:

```
boolean result = PrimeTest(n);
if(result)
    System.out.println(n + " is a prime number!");
if(!result)
    System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number!");
```

Your prompt isn't working because you don't reset valid to false before asking the second time:

```
valid = false;
while(!valid)
```